# Reminder emails sent to AOL email addresses are blank

Tags: html, email, windows-vista, aol, mjml

I built an email reminder template using [MJML](https://mjml.io/). I've received complaints from three clients that the email they received from me is blank. The only discernible pattern is that they are all aol users. I had one of them send me a screenshot.

[image: Blank AOL Email Image]

This client's computer is Windows Vista and using Firefox to display it. I haven't received responses from my other clients.

I created an aol email for testing and sent a reminder in the same way my other clients would receive them.

[image: Expected AOL Email Image]

It works correctly for me. (Windows 10 using  Firefox)
Does anyone know whats causing this?

Comment: Please post your html code so we can see what solution you're using.

Comment: Check for HTML comments in the head of the document, around CSS area and yes post your code for a proper solution.

Comment: Sending HTML emails from an email client (say, Outlook) is usually tough because so many clients (all?) change the HTML before sending it. Try using an Email Service Provider. You can send a free test at putsmail.com (don't ask it to inline CSS); they won't change your HTML.